# How to find the maximum percentage error in the following case?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Suppose the ideal gas equation $R=\frac{PV}{T}$ has $R$ as constant. If the percentage error in measuring $P,V,T$ are $1$%, $2$% and $3$%, how to find the maximum percentage error in $R$? In this question, I think we first need to find the differential of $R$
$$dR=\frac{V}{T}dP+\frac{P}{T}dV-\frac{PV}{T^2}dT$$
Dividing both sides by $R$, we get $$\frac{dR}{R}=\frac{dP}{P}+\frac{dV}{V}-\frac{dT}{T}$$

But since we do not the know the exact value of $V, T$ and $P$, how are we going to find the result?

Comment: Hint: Divide both sides of the above equation by $R$.

Comment: Sorry, I still couldn't derive the result.

Comment: Go to $\Delta$'s. Everything will correspond to relative errors.

Comment: I would straightforward use the numbers. The numerator has to be as large as possible and the denominator has to be as small as possible.

$max \ dR/R=\frac{1.01\cdot 1.02}{0.97}-1$

Comment: @callculus: As the error can go in both sides, you need also to compute $\frac{0.99·0.98}{1.03}-1$ to capture the full range of possible values.

Comment: @LutzL Yes if it is asked for the range. But I thought that it is asked for the maximum difference of the true value and the measured value. I get $6.2\%$

Comment: @callculus That is true, but one still has to lose a word or two on why the second variant gives less an absolute error than the first.

Comment: @LutzL You´re right, I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage error is the error divided by the true value, which is exactly what you have.  You are given $\left|\frac {\Delta V}V\right|  \lt 0.02$ and so on.  You are being asked to compute the upper limit on $\left|\frac {\Delta R}R\right| $